# How to generate Structural connectivity(SC) and Functional connectivity(FC) matrices from raw fMRI data?

Tags: fmri

I am working with The Virtual Brain (TVB) software and require SC and FC matrices as inputs. I have raw rs-fMRI data (T1-w and DTI). Can someone please suggest an end-to-end pipeline for pre-processing raw data and generating the SC and FC matrices?

I have already tried working with [Empirical processing pipeline for TVB](https://github.com/BrainModes/TVB-empirical-data-pipeline) and [Surface and Connectivity Reconstruction Imaging Pipeline for TVB Simulations](https://github.com/ins-amu/scripts/wiki). But both of them are not working. The first one is meant to be run on a high-performance cluster using the SLURM job scheduler.